# Why a java method is related to an object rather than a class?

Tags: java, object, implementation

I have a question about java's method reference in the following format;

acollection.foreach(System.out::println);

I would expect the code to be something similar to;

acollection.foreach(System.PrintStream::println);

Would you please explain the idea behind relating implementation(code) to an object?

Comment: Well, OOP isn't short for class-oriented programming ... So if you don't know what OOP is, then do research about that? Ask Google and Wikipedia first.

Comment: In `forEach(System.out::println)`, you're asking to call `println` on the actual object `System.out`. There's no such thing as `System.PrintStream`. And if there was, how would Java know _what_ printstream you're trying to print with?

Answer (score 0):

`PrintStream.println()` is an instance method and thus has to be executed on an instance (object).

`acollection.foreach(System.out::println);` does just that. It will execute `println` on `System.out` for each element in the collection.

`acollection.foreach(System.PrintStream::println);` can't work because no instance of `PrintStream` is given - and also because `System.PrintStream` is not a valid statement.